# Application.DisplayAlerts = False no cambia a false

Tags: excel, vba

Estimados les pido ayuda, hace poco reinstale otra versión de office 2007 (Me es necesario trabajar con esta version)y resulta que dentro de otras dificultades actualmente al ejecutar

*Application.DisplayAlerts = Fal*se

la variable **jamas pasa a ser falsa**, tanto en el modo de ejecución como revisión paso a paso

alguien sabe porque podría estar pasando esto? no he encontrado una respuesta clara

Comment: *la variable jamas pasa a ser falsa, tanto en el modo de ejecución como revisión paso a paso* ¿Cómo que no pasa a ser Falsa? ¿Te siguen saliendo alertas?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Pon un ejemplo del código donde estás utilizando DIsplayAlerts. Podría ser que estés utilizando un objeto (CreateObject("Excel.Application")) y no estés referenciando bien.